# Writing a Lisp macro with nested quasiquoting

Tags: macros, lisp

I'm trying to write a Lisp macro that writes a bunch of macros, but I'm having problems generating macro code that uses the splice operator (in build-bind) that expands inside expressions first.

```lisp
(defmacro define-term-construct (name filter-p list-keywords)
  (let* ((do-list-name (output-symbol "do-~a-list" name))
         (with-name (output-symbol "with-~a" name))
         (do-filter-name (output-symbol "do-~as" name)))
   `(progn
       (defmacro ,do-list-name 
         (ls (&key ,@(append list-keywords '(id operation))) &body body)
          (with-gensyms (el)
           `(loop-list (,el ,ls :id ,id :operation ,operation)
              (let (XXX,@(build-bind ,,name ,el))
                 (when (,',filter-p ,el)
                    (,',with-name ,el
                          ,@body)))))))))
```

After the first pass I want to get:

```lisp
(define-term-construct some some-p (args name))

->

(PROGN
  (DEFMACRO DO-SOME-LIST (LS (&KEY ARGS NAME ID OPERATION) &BODY BODY)
   (WITH-GENSYMS (EL)
     `(LOOP-LIST (,EL ,LS :ID ,ID :OPERATION ,OPERATION)
        (LET (,@(BUILD-BIND ,SOME ,EL))
         (WHEN (SOME-P ,EL)
           (WITH-SOME ,EL
              ,@BODY)))))))
```

Any idea what quote/quasiquotes should I use to get the desired code?

Comment: You should show your code more completely. That is, including all your macro's helper functions like `do-list-name`, etc.

Comment: `do-list-name` will be the macro generated by `define-term-construct` . I just want to know how to output the splice operator in nested quasiquotting.

Comment: And `output-symbol` is just something like `(intern (format nil <string> <arg>))` I take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output that you say that you want want to get has unbalanced commas. `,@` already balances the backquote, so you cannot have `,SOME` and `,EL`. That's two levels of unquoting/splicing inside only one level of backquoting.

I suspect you want:

```
`(WITH-GENSYMS (EL) ... (LET (,@(BUILD-BIND 'SOME EL)) ...))
```

The `some` symbol comes in as an argument to the original macro and has to end up as a quoted symbol when passed to the `build-bind` function. The `EL` is evaluated straight. It's just a local variable introduced by the `WITH-GENSYMS` binding construct, and it is not in backquote context anymore because it is inside the splice.

Transliterating that back to the the original outer macro's backquote: `SOME` becomes `,name`:

```
,@(build-bind ',name el)  ;; two commas out balance two backquotes in
```

The symbol is spliced in under the umbrella of a protecting quote which will make sure it is treated as a symbol and not a variable.

The `el` does not need to be spliced in; it's not variable material but a hard-coded feature of the template being generated. If you were to put `,el` it would look for an `el` variable in the `define-term-construct` macro's scope, where no such thing exists.